# How to find all objects deleted by user in specified time

Tags: openstreetmap

Is there any way to get list of objects with their geometries deleted by specified user in specified time?

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible by doing a few queries. First, [get the changesets](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Query%3a_GET_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2Fchangesets) of the user in question. There is also a time parameter which I remember to be very tricky to use, alternatively get all changesets and iterate through them until the time matches. Then parse each changeset for deleted objects (objects where the *time* attribute is *false*). And finally retrieve the *previous version* of these deleted objects in order to get all the information you are looking for.

But remember that objects can be restored. Just because an object is deleted at version *x* it doesn't have to be deleted at version *x+1* any more!

Comment: Wow, that's tricky... I don't know if not too much tricky for me, but if there will not be another option i'll try this. I was expecting some simplest resolution based on Overpass Api (4 ex.). Thanx 4 your time :)

Comment: With the new attic feature of the Overpass API you should at least be able to query all changes of a specific user within a specified time range (adiff). For more information see talk-de announcement [Overpass API v0.7.50 almost done](http://gis.19327.n5.nabble.com/Overpass-API-v0-7-50-almost-done-td5808154.html) and [SotM EU workshop](http://www.sotm-eu.org/en/slots/37)

Comment: @NorbertRenner Yes, I remembered this new feature, too. But haven't played with it yet. Maybe someone is able to create a less complex solution with the help of this feature.